# Can someone explain to me this type (() => void)[] = []

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I came across this type `(() => void)[] = []`
can someone explain it to me

```
public functionName: (() => void)[] = []
```

is it a function that doesn't return but I don't understand the rest of the array syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's variable of type: array of parameterless functions which don't return values.
Initialized with empty array.

Comment: [] = [] this means Initialized with empty array.

Comment: Yes, it's the same as:
  let arr: (() => void)[];
  arr = [];

Comment: Just as a suggestion, avoid using `[]` for arrays if the item type is a complex type (ie not just a type name). `Array<() => void>` is much more readable IMO.

Answer (score 1):

It is an array of functions

```
public functionName: 
   (() => void)[]  // array of functions that take no parameter and return nothing
   = [] // initialization of functionName with an empty array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public numbers: number[] = []
```

This is a variable called numbers and it's an array of number.
Now the important part is to understand the

```
()=>void
(x) => return x
```

This is a simple lambda expression (You can google more about that). But the gist of it is that the left part are the parameters passed and the right part is the implementation.
So your expression is a array that contains lambda expressions. I am simply elaborating on Tomasz Iz answer so you can comprehend it better.

Comment: It doesn't have to be lambda expressions; it's any function that can be called with zero arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit late, and answer has been given already, but I still want to give a deeper one.

The type `X[]` means an array of `X`.

The type `()=>void` means a function that returns nothing.

In type expressions you can group things with parenthesis too, in order to avoid inconsistencies.

So the type `(X)` is the same type as `X`.

So `(()=>void)[]` means an array of functions that return nothing.

Note: Nothing, is not the same as `never`. At least not in this case. TS is such a cool type system over such a mess of a language (JS)... It tries so hard to be cool and awesome and at the same type it is dragged down by JS.

Functions in JS may halt/complete/finish without returning a value.
That in functional languages, where every function returns something, means returning `Unit`... as in a type that only has one runtime representation: a tuple of zero arity. How many tuples of zero arity exist?... 1. A value that represent that a procedure ended, BUT also a value that contains no relevant information (it can be ignored).

On the other side there's the case of functions actually not returning anything. It means, functions that either fail, or that they actually never finish (i.e `()=>{while(true){}}`).

That "type" that represents it, is known as `never` in TS, `Void` in Haskell, `Nothing` in Scala and Kotlin and yep, that'it

The `Unit` type that I talked about previously doesn't actually have a representing type in TS... (although it could be represented easily with the type `null`, `undefined`, and in some cases `void`). In Kotlin and Scala it is known as `Unit` and in Haskell is referred to as Unit, but written `()` (a tuple of zero arity).
In Java is represented somehow by `void` methods, but if you ask me, I think that's just bad design. They are not exactly methods that return unit, but methods that don't return (just as in TS and JS).

Which I think, it's just bad design.